# Проблема с подключением к БД. Unable to complete network request to host "localhost"

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms, firebird

Делаю программу для синхронизации бд программы учета, бд сайта и файлов с остатками от поставщиков.

Подключение к mysql бд сайта - без проблем. А с firebird бд программы учета - проблемы.

Возникает следующая ошибка.
[image: 1]

Вроде как все понятно. Но нет.

Использую RazorSQL, которым без проблем подключаюсь к базе данных.
Порт дефолтный. 3050. Брандмауэр вообще не включается и в службах его нету, походу он умер.

Код следующий...

```
FbConnectionStringBuilder cs = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
           
            cs.DataSource = "localhost";
            cs.Database = @"C:\\ProgramData\UkrSklad7\db\Sklad.tcb";
            cs.UserID = "SYSDBA";
            cs.Password = "masterkey";
            cs.ServerType = FbServerType.Default;
            cs.Dialect = 3;
            cs.Pooling = false;
            cs.Port = 3050;

            fbCon = new FbConnection(cs.ToString());

            fbCon.Open();
```

Жду ваши идеи. Для быстрой связи телеграмм. @nnoommaadd

Comment: А сам сервер firebird на машине запущен?

Comment: А вот хотел бы я сказать да, но точно не уверен. Бд создаётся программой учета. Вполне возможно, что и запускается она не вместе с системой, а программой учета.     Как можно наверняка проверить это..?

Но RazorSQL видит базу в независимости от того, работает ли программа учета, может ли быть такое, что он тоже ее сам запускает.

Comment: Проверить можно командой `telnet localhost 3050`. Если появится черная консоль, значит работает. Если ошибка подключения - значит нет.